# including a connection string generates error in asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have set up a small SQL Server database for users to login and also create accounts. There is a problem with the connection string though. Whenever I use the connection string below in the web.config file I get a  server error page and cannot view the website. However when I take out this connection string I am able to view the website albeit the database doesn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <addname="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=medicale_Members;User ID=user_admin;Password=medicalmembers;"/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
```

Comment: What does the error page say, and the connection string wasn't posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
</connectionStrings>
```

Also as another person mentioned. Change the add to:

```
<add name ... />
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if it's a typo in your question, but you need to ensure your connection string element looks like:

```
 <add name
```

rather than

```
<addname
```

Ensure you close your element with

```
 </connectionStrings>
```